# SKLabel.text Integer not updating - swift

Tags: string, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

[image: crash screen/ error message]
Im creating a game and i have created and integer which keeps track of the number of enemies killed, however i can not get the sklabel on the UI to update. no matter how many enemies the integer kept displaying 0. Here are some of the methods i have tried

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var Enemy1KillCounter = 0
var Enemy1KillCounterLabel = SKLabelNode ()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    createEnemyKilledLabel()
}

func createEnemyKilledLabel() {

    Enemy1KillCounterLabel.fontSize = 65
    Enemy1KillCounterLabel.fontColor = SKColor .blackColor()
    Enemy1KillCounterLabel.position = CGPointMake(400, 400)
    self.addChild(Enemy1KillCounterLabel)
}

func updateEnemy1KillCounter() {

    Enemy1KillCounter += 1
    Enemy1KillCounterLabel.text = "\(Enemy1KillCounter)"
    score = score + 15
    //enemy1Killed = true   I had tried Boolean values as well 
    print("updateEnemy1KillCounter")

}
    //this method is called in my enemy1 class when its "killed"
func Enemy1DieG () {

    updateEnemy1KillCounter()

    }
}
```

i have also tried using the update method with boolean values implicated multiple different ways but none worked.

```
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if enemy1Killed {Enemy1KillCounter += 1}
    Enemy1KillCounterLabel.text = "\(Enemy1KillCounter)"

 }
```

here is my enemy class and where i am calling the "enemy1DieG" method

I call the hit method in a contact method but i know that is not the issue because when the enemy is is "killed" when it is hit 5x's so the enemy1die and killCounter methods are being called

```
class Enemy1: SKNode {

var Enemy1Health:Int = 50

 func hit() ->Bool {

Enemy1Health -= 10
Bullet1GoAway = true

if ( Enemy1Health <= 0 ) {

        Enemy1Die()
    return true
    } else {
    return false
}
}
func Enemy1Die () {
    self.removeFromParent()
    Enemy1KillCounter()
}

func Enemy1KillCounter (){
    GameScene().Enemy1DieG()
}
}
```

its so weird all of the methods are being called i used print values on each method to make sure but my integer is not updating in my UI it just keeps displaying 0. This is probably such an easy answer and I keep missing it, if anybody can help that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inside `Enemy1KillCounter()` you write

```
GameScene().Enemy1DieG()
```

you are **NOT** using the GameScene shown on the screen.

Instead you are temporarily creating a new empty screen, invoking `Enemy1DieG()` on it and they destroying it.

Please replace this

```
func Enemy1KillCounter (){
    GameScene().Enemy1DieG()
}
```

with this

```
func Enemy1KillCounter() {
    guard let gameScene = self.scene as? GameScene
        else { fatalError("Current node is not inside a GameScene") }
    gameScene.Enemy1DieG()
}
```

Comment: for your 1st theory - are you only able to have 1 SKlabel per scene? or do you mean i have 2 of the same labels and I'm printing one and not the other    for your 2nd - my background is grey so i can see that it is displaying 0 its just not updating and for your third- what do you men where does the label come from? i created the label in the game scene class and call it in the view method @appzYourLife

Comment: @gkolman: you can have as many labels as you want. I suspect there is another label in your scene (the one visible via the simulator), this would explain why the changes to `Enemy1KillCounterLabel` aren't visible. I updated by answer with a test code. Please use it and let me know what you see in your label into the simulator.

Comment: the text says "Do you see me?" lol how should i proceed? @appzYourLife

Comment: yessir :D @appzYourLife and i changed my variables to lowercase

Comment: @gkolman: Then I don't understand. Another question. When an enemy gets killed, how are you calling `enemy1DieG()`? Can you show me the full block of code?

Comment: Just added my enemy class @appzYourLife thanks for the help

Comment: i implemented your code, thank you for your help however, is there anything else i am missing? The screen integer is still not updating :( it still displays a 0 @appzYourLife

Comment: Do you have any other ideas as to why it is not updating? @appzYourLife i have been stuck on this for like 2 days :(

Comment: @gkolman: if you want you can send me your project: info@appzyourlife.com

Comment: Ok i implemented your code and it crashes on this line(I added a screenshot of the crash), i feel like if we fix the crash it should work fine lol @appzYourLife

Comment: @gkolman: good we are very close. It means that when you invoke `Enemy1KillerCounter()` your `Enemy has already been removed from the your scene. Can you change your code to call `Enemy1KillerCounter()` *before* the `Enemy` is removed?

Comment: oh, i just actually read the whole error... lol i figure it out. thank you soooooo much you have finally stopped my headache haha. It would have taken me a couple more days to figure that out on my own. thanks for the help you're a rockstar @appzYourLife

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114275/discussion-between-appzyourlife-and-gkolman).